# Get location along a path or line upon click in d3

Tags: d3.js

As stated in the title, I was wondering how to catch the location along a path or line of a mouse click - is it simply using the `mousedown` event and then calculating the `d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY` as it matches the line? Is there a better way?

Comment: are you saying you want the point on the path where click happened?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm saying - it would be great to have it in relative form rather than absolute.

Comment: and relative to what..

Comment: Relative to the svg block ie with the coordinates of the point over the path/line being clicked, so that an animation can be placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `d3.mouse` function.

> ## d3.mouse(container)
>
> Returns the x and y coordinates of the current d3.event, relative to
>   the specified container. The container may be an HTML or SVG container
>   element, such as an svg:g or svg:svg. The coordinates are returned as
>   a two-element array [x, y].

Reference: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_mouse

**Example:** (Try clicking on the path)

```js
var points = [
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100],
  [780, 300],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 500);

var path = svg.append("path")
  .data([points])
  .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed"));

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", "red")
  .attr("cx", points[0][0])
  .attr("cy", points[0][1]);

path.on("click", function() {
  circle.attr("cx", d3.mouse(this)[0])
    .attr("cy", d3.mouse(this)[1]);
});
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The ball doesn't seem to be always centered on the path. Would you happen to know the reason for this and how it could be corrected?

Comment: Currently when user click on the path,  cx and cy attributes of circle is set with the exact click position.